# How to manage customized keycloak SPIs, Entities, Rest endpoints on the top of the keycloak version?

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-services

I have been trying to add customized keycloak SPIs, entities and rest endpoint. I would like to know the best approach to maintain them on the top of keycloak code. Secondly, I have done some hands on with domain extension provider, but I couldn't get success to integrate with keycloak disctribution. Could you please help me with some more examples or steps to implement keycloak SPIs, entities and rest endpoints apart from keycloak documentations.

Answer (score 0):

Keycloak customized providers can be kept as a separate maven project in your favorite IDE with dependencies from keycloak SPIs.
Build it, copy the jar file and paste it in the providers or deployments folder based on the nature of extension you are building.
I would suggest you to clone the keycloak source and understand- how they have implemented some of the SPI, identify the patterns.

You can also write it to their dev mailing list i.e. keycloak-dev@lists.jboss.org for more details.